# How can I write a C# method to clear a group of checkboxes upon button click?

Tags: c#, checkbox

New C# problem...

I'm supposed to write 6 separate methods to clear 6 groups of checkboxes (all at once) when I click the clear button. I know how to code it with individual checkboxes, but the problem asks for me to create a method and then call all 6 of them upon clicking the clear button. Help?

I have nothing associated with the clearButton_Click event yet.

```
    private void ClearOilLube
    {
        set {oilChangeCheckBox.Checked = false;
        lubeJobCheckBox.Checked = false;}
    }

    private void ClearFlushes
    {
        set {radiatorFlushCheckBox.Checked = false; 
        transFlushCheckBox.Checked = false;}
    }

    private void ClearMisc
    {
        set {inspectionCheckBox.Checked = false;
        replaceMufflerCheckBox.Checked = false;
        tireRotationCheckBox.Checked = false;}
    }

    private void ClearOther
    {
        set {partsCostInputTextBox.Text = null;
        laborInputTextBox.Text = null;}
    }

    private void ClearFees
    {
        set {servicesLaborDispLabel.Text = null;
        partsDispLabel.Text = null;
        partsTaxDispLabel.Text = null;
        totalFeesDispLabel.Text = null;}
    }
```

Comment: Is this a WinForm or WebForm?  Get to the collection of controls, and iterate through them.

Comment: It's a Windows Form. Iterate? What?

Comment: Have the `button_Click` call all the clearing methods?

Comment: Iterate means looping through a list/array. Get all the controls on a window/panel/othercontrol and check if they are matching your description.

Comment: You said you know how to clear them individually just call all the methods that are used to clear the individual ones.

Comment: I'm a little tired... my book isnt super clear to me... so how do I call a method in a button_click? I prefer to see the correct code so my mind will link to it correctly. 

Somehow, I need to use the 6 methods to clear each group of checkboxes instead of:

checkBox1.Checked = false;
checkBox2.Checked = false; and etc... 

I want to call/use the 6 methods... and I'm not even sure if I set up the private void methods correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the clear button is clicked just call the methods you created above to clear the data.

```
public void clearButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClearOilLube();
    ClearFlushes();
    ClearMisc();
    ClearOther();
    ClearFees();

    // May be required to be called to ensure the UI is up to date.
    Update();
}
```

**Edit**

The syntax on your question is a little strange. They are written kind of like properties when they should be methods. No 'set' or 'get' is needed. Just make them regular helper methods.

This is just typed in no testing on a compiler or IDE but what I can see is fixed.

```
private void ClearOilLube()
{
    oilChangeCheckBox.Checked = false;
    lubeJobCheckBox.Checked = false;
}

private void ClearFlushes()
{
    radiatorFlushCheckBox.Checked = false; 
    transFlushCheckBox.Checked = false;
}

private void ClearMisc()
{
    inspectionCheckBox.Checked = false;
    replaceMufflerCheckBox.Checked = false;
    tireRotationCheckBox.Checked = false;
}

private void ClearOther()
{
    partsCostInputTextBox.Text = "";
    laborInputTextBox.Text = "";
}

private void ClearFees()
{
    servicesLaborDispLabel.Text = "";
    partsDispLabel.Text = "";
    partsTaxDispLabel.Text = "";
    totalFeesDispLabel.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: Well, that's stupid easy... :P

Do I use set or... I  don't think I setup the void methods fully right either.

Comment: Your approach is the easiest.

Answer (score 4):

Your methods (or is that properties?) are written quite badly. I will just assume that you want to write *methods* not *properties*.

Method headers take the following form: (simplified)

```
[access modifier] {return value type} {method name} ([parameter list])
```

So your methods should look like this:

```
    private void ClearOilLube ()
    {
        oilChangeCheckBox.Checked = false;
        lubeJobCheckBox.Checked = false;
    }

    private void ClearFlushes ()
    {
        radiatorFlushCheckBox.Checked = false; 
        transFlushCheckBox.Checked = false;
    }

    private void ClearMisc ()
    {
        inspectionCheckBox.Checked = false;
        replaceMufflerCheckBox.Checked = false;
        tireRotationCheckBox.Checked = false;
    }

    private void ClearOther ()
    {
        partsCostInputTextBox.Text = null;
        laborInputTextBox.Text = null;
    }

    private void ClearFees ()
    {
        servicesLaborDispLabel.Text = null;
        partsDispLabel.Text = null;
        partsTaxDispLabel.Text = null;
        totalFeesDispLabel.Text = null;
    }
```

And then, you can call these methods one by one in the onClick method.

However, a better approach is to loop through (or iterate) through the Controls of the form.

```
private void ClearButtonClick (object sender, EventArgs e) {
    foreach (Control control in this.Controls) {
        if (control is CheckBox) {
            ((CheckBox)control).Checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

If you still don't understand, tell me in the comments!

Comment: Just curious why you think the better approach is to iterate the Controls?

Comment: It's quicker to write. @JBlaz

Comment: True but if he has a lot of controls (I doubt he does) this is defiantly not the best way...

Comment: I know my methods were awful... I was trying to figure out the missing pieces... ie: private void ClearOilLube() and then calling it in the button_click event...

The book wasn't super clear on that or I'm dumb and just read right over it.

Answer (score 2):

To give you an alternative, though it is more complex:

```
private void GetAllControlsOfType<TControl>(TControl collection, List<TControl> container) where TControl : Control
{
     foreach(Control control in collection)
     {
          if(control is TControl)
               container.Add(control);

          if(control.HasControls())
               GetAllControlsOfType<TControl>(control.Controls, container); 
     }
}
```

Then to utilize, you would simply do:

```
var checkboxes = new List<Checkbox>();
GetAllControlsOfType<Checkbox>(Page.Controls, checkboxes);
```

After that is executed it will contain a `List` of all the checkbox controls.  Then you could simply map them to the state of the `object` or you can simply do the following:

```
foreach(var checkbox in checkboxes)
     checkbox.Checked = false;
```

That would uncheck all, keep in mind this hasn't been tested so it may need some fine tuning.

Comment: Your approach could be more elegant.